# FATCA IDES Response message decryption

Tags: public-key-encryption

I have successfully uploaded the fatca data packets to IDES. I got response from IDES, now I want to decrypt the messages.

Whenever i tried to decypt using our private key it throws "BAD DATA" error.
I have verified my certificate is valid, and we uploaded same certificate to IDES at the time of registration.

I am using c#.net as per IDES guidelines.

What might be the error and any areas which I can cross check?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I had published a tool for this.

It's the [IDES receiver](http://shadiakiki1986.github.io/IDES-Receiver/) and it's source code is [here](https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/IDES-Receiver).

It's written in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use the official IDES Data Tool, this one has been validated by the IRS and you can download it from https://github.com/IRSgov/IDES-Data-Preparation-Dot-Net.

1. Install the IDES tool
2. Open the Decrypt Notification tab
3. Upload the received Data Packet
4. Check your Output folder, you should have the Data Packet unzipped, and among others the XML decrypted.

If you have still problems with this process you can also debug this application from the source code.